# Threading Manners: What is an acceptable hit rate for a web API?

Tags: c#, xml, web-applications

Say an HTTP web service is serving up some XML data loads.  Because it's a parameterized web call, lots of calls will need to be made to match up data to say, an internal database. The end goal is to turn this a C# ETL project with a daily schedule run.  **What is considered good manners from a resource perspective on the number of concurrent connections?**

As a first stab, I was considering 10 threads per second.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Depends, if you are hitting your buddies webserver who pays $1/kb, or are you working on an Google Cloud API? Usually you would say "let the webmaster limit me" or follow whatever the API says. Some expensive API's will rate/connection limit themselves.

Comment: Not working on the Google API, but could use Google as an example. The unnamed service hasn't explicitly specified, and just trying ease into it per se